# Kotlin: Count No of occurrences of string in string

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

```
val string = "5 kg rice 2 kg wheat 3 kg Soya"
```

Is there any higher-order function to count String "kg" in the above string?

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is:

```
val count = s.split("kg").size - 1
```

After you split your string by using **split** extension function, size minus one gives you the occurence count.

you can test this solution on Kotlin Playground:
https://pl.kotl.in/y6Sciwgzk

Comment: Fantastic answer!! Succinct & exactly what I needed.  Really like how you solved this.  Kudos!

Comment: I went with val count = s.split("kg").size.minus(1)

Answer (score 6):

```
fun main() {
    val s = "5 kg rice 2 kg wheat 3 kg Soya"
    val c = "\\bkg\\b".toRegex().findAll(s).count()
    println(c)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be no function from the standard library that counts substrings. But you can easily write an extension function that uses the `indexOf(element, startIndex)` function:

```
fun main() {
    val string = "5 kg rice 2 kg wheat 3 kg Soya"
    
    println(string.count("kg"))
}

fun String.count(element: String): Int {
    var count = 0
    
    // Check if the string contains the element at all
    var lastIndex = indexOf(element, 0)
    while (lastIndex >= 0) {
        count += 1

        // Find the next occurence
        lastIndex = indexOf(element, lastIndex + 1) 
    }
    
    return count
}
```

Comment: What i did is string.split("kg").size-1

Comment: Ah, @ice spirit that's even cooler, you could add it as an answer.

Comment: The split method is somewhat more inefficient. In a short test with 10,000 iterations, the split takes about 2.5 times as long.

Comment: Should be lastIndex > -1 instead of lastIndex > 0. Otherwise this method won't work if "element" is at the start of the string

Comment: @Krill Oh right, thanks for the hint. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
println("5 kg rice 2 kg wheat 3 kg Soya".windowed(2, 1).count { it == "kg" })
```

But if you only want the occurrences of " kg ", you can use:

```
println("5 kg rice 2 kg wheat 3 kg Soyakg".windowed(4, 1).count { it == " kg " })
```

I believe it could work also:

```
println("5 kg rice 2 kg wheat 3 kg Soya".splitToSequence(" kg ").count() - 1)
```

As I said before the way you split the string or check the windowed string will depend on what kind of occurrence you consider valid.